# Evaluating a 2D function successively with each pair of values in a list of pairs

Tags: core-language

I have a table of parameter pairs `a` and `b` `{{a1, b1}, {a2, b2}, ...}` and I would like to evaluate a function with these parameter pairs. What I tried so far:

```
Table[a + b, {a, {1, 2}}, {b, {3, 4}}]
```

As a result I do get:

> ```
> {{4, 5}, {5, 6}}
> ```

So Mathematica evaluated the function `a + b` with all possible combinations of the list of `a` and `b`. However, I would like to have a table with the evaluation of the fuction 1st with `a = 1` and `b = 3` and then with `a = 2` and `b = 4` and not the other combinations. How do I realize this?

Comment: `MapThread[foo, {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}]` or `Inner[foo, {1, 2}, {3, 4}, List]` or `foo @@@ Transpose[{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}]` or `Thread[foo[{1, 2}, {3, 4}]]` ??

Comment: ... use `Plus` for `foo` to get your `a+b` example.

Comment: `f @@@ {{1, 3}, {2, 4}}`?

Answer (score 2):

[`Apply[f, {ab1, ab2,...}, {1}]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Apply.html) or [`f @@@ {ab1, ab2,...}`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/25616#25616):

```
Plus @@@ {{1, 3}, {2, 4}}
(* {4, 6} *)

Plus @@@ {{1, 3}, {2, 4}, {3, 5}}
(* {4, 6, 8} *)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: @JPK You're welcome. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
Thread[foo[{a, b}, {c, d}]]
foo @@@ Thread[{{a, b}, {c, d}}]
foo @@@ Transpose[{{a, b}, {c, d}}]
Inner[foo, {a, b}, {c, d}, List]
MapThread[foo, {{a, b}, {c, d}}]
```

> {foo[a, c], foo[b, d]}

For `Plus` you can simply  use (thanks: MichaelE2)

```
{a, b} + {c, d} (* or *)
Plus[{a, b}, {c, d}]
```

to get

> {a + c, b + d}

Actually, the same is true for all [`Listable`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Listable.html) functions such as `Times` and `Power`:

```
Times[{a, b, c}, {x, y, z}]
```

> {a x, b y, c z}

```
{a,b,c}^{x,y,z}
```

> {a^x, b^y, c^z}

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: @JPK, my pleasure.